# programatically get facebook friends' details in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to android. I am creating an app which synchronizes Facebook contacts with phone contacts. I am using the Facebook api 4.0 . Now I don't know how to get all my friends' details.

I tried `user_friends` which gives only friends details who are using my app. But I want all friends details.

Comment: What did you tried so far? What problem did you face?

Comment: I tried graph api me/friends which give friends list who use my app. But I want all friends details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently and failed... The problem is that Facebook has changed its privacy policy and the new Graph API does not let you even get the list of your friends unless your app is a game created on canvas.
You can use the old Graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/user/), but it WILL stop working on April, 30, as they say here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog.
So the answer is: it's impossible.

Comment: then how come there are many apps like syncMe in play store which sync facebook, linkedin etc contacts. ? How android cellphone it self has that option in Settings ?

Comment: As I said - there still is an API v1.0 that supports getting all friends from Facebook. Here you have the docs:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/user/friends
However, it will get deprecated on April, 30, which is posted on FB changelog:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog